# Can we change the BASEURL in environment prod file in angular from frontend dropdown button?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to change the baseurl after angular build using dropdown point in the application.

How can I link to the environment file and change baseurl based on the dropdown value?

.html file

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Select Environment</label><br>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="valueChange($event)">
       <option [value]="option" *ngFor="let option of envOptions">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

.ts file

```js
dropdown = new FormControl();
envOptions = ["Production", "Development", "Testing"];
selected: any = "Production";

valueChange(event) {
    console.log(
      "selected value", event.target.value,
      "value of selected",this.selected
    );
  }
```

environment.prod.ts

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  BASE_URL: "http://ipaddress:1111", //prod
  // BASE_URL: "http://ipaddress:2222", // dev
  // BASE_URL: "http://ipaddress:3333", // testing
};
```

Will this work if the environment baseurl changes from the frontend and no other settings needs to be changed?

I'm new to angular any feedback on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot manage BASE URL with single environment file. for that we have to create multiple environments

1. `environment.prod.ts`

```js
export const environment = {
   production: true,
   BASE_URL: "http://ipaddress:1111"
};
```

2. `environment.dev.ts`

```js
export const environment = {
   production: false,
   BASE_URL: "http://ipaddress:2222"
};
```

3. `environment.testing.ts`

```js
export const environment = {
   production: true,
   BASE_URL: "http://ipaddress:3333"
};
```

Create above there files in environments folder

4. Update angular.json configuration

In your Angular project, you shall find angular.json file. Inside this file, you can add a new section under projects/architect/build section.

```json
"production": {
   "fileReplacements": [
        {
            "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
            "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    ],
},
"dev": {
    "fileReplacements": [
         {
             "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
             "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
         }
    ]
},
"testing": {
    "fileReplacements": [
         {
             "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
             "with": "src/environments/environment.testing.ts"
         }
    ]
}
```

5. Build application for custom environment

Once your configuration is done, you can build your application for targeted environment by specific --configuration parameter to ng build command. For example, to build application in dev mode, run command

```
ng build --prod --configuration dev
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, got to know new things how to implement them. 
Still I have a small question that can we able to change from UI as a dropdown for which environment to use. so that after deployment I don't want to rebuild again and again for different environments. Its like once after deployment I can change whichever environment I want?

Comment: @Rahul , we cannot rewrite the file in frontend means if you select BASEURL form dropdown that key need to replace with existing key that will done when we resave the file

Comment: Oh! so the only option left is to rebuild the application every time and upload it to the server?
Can we use any external js file to change the environment? (just a thought)

Comment: Is there a way to replace the existing prod URL with a dev URL or test URL in environments using dropdown? (just wanted to reduce rebuild tasks so this thought pops up in my mind).